# In C is it possible to change http requests to https

Tags: c, http, https

Long story short I've got this package that currently has a security risk where credentials are sent over http and I need to convert them to https but I currently lack the knowledge to do so. Could anyone point me in the right direction on how to go about this?

Just for the record I did not create this program but became its proxy maintainer for Gentoo as to keep it available for the community and since its kinda my first package I don't want to lose it.

Comment: There's no way to answer this as it requires lots of information about what exactly you are doing with HTTP, what libraries you are using, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're asking how to take "http data" and convert it to "https data" so that it's automatically more secure when you send it into the internet. That's not how it works.

HTTPS is a different protocol, in which SSL is used to establish a secure connection with the other endpoint before sending regular HTTP packets. Whether you want to set this up directly with OpenSSL or a higher-level library depends on what your program is trying to accomplish and what library/ies it's currently using for networking.

Comment: I'm aware that they are different protocols, the program in particular is Noip's dynamic update client for Linux. Currently I can see the code but as I said I know nothing about C but a point in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: What library does it use to talk HTTP (cURL maybe?) ? Look into this library and check if you can do HTTPS instead.

Comment: Looking at the code it seems it uses wget instead. Some of the comments left from the developers make it seem that way anyways.

Actually I just tried to access the URL that is used for the updating and they don't even have https on their site at all so even if I fixed the client it wouldn't work at all. I feel I can't win for losing here.

Comment: If the server doesn't support HTTPS there is indeed nothing you can do.

Answer (score 0):

I would not touch the C program. I suggest that you put apache in front of it. You can easily configure apache for https (you will need to get a cert).
You will need to google how to set up a "reverse proxy".
Apache will then act as the front door and forward the http requests to your other process on an internal port.